# Rolling shutter on light sources

Tags: rendering

Title is fairly self explanatory, trying to get a rolling shutter effect on fast strobing light sources but everything I try doesn't seem to make any difference, is rolling shutter only calculated for objects or something?

Comment: Do you mean emissive objects?  If you mean "lamp" objects, I don't believe they actually have a physical manifestation.

Comment: I mean any light source but spot lights specifically in this case, I'm keyframing the power to flash at sub frame intervals (something like 0.6 frames) and I want the rolling shutter to mimic how a real shutter would be slow enough to only expose part of the sensor while the light is on.
Example vid here (avoid if you have epilepsy): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF_9FhAlxi4

Comment: are you actually modelling a shutter opening and closing?  I don't think the light sources are physically correct enough to work like real light sources.

Comment: I tried animating a rotationally arrayed plane for a rolling shutter but it only worked as it should for moving objects, the lights were either visible in the whole frame or totally invisible. I also tried using emissive objects and scaling them back and forth from 0, same result as the lights

Comment: Think I'm gonna do it in compositing by isolating each light source and masking their direct and indirect passes with horizontal stripes, will post as an answer if I get a decent result

Comment: Have you tried encasing the light sources inside a cylinder, deleting some of the faces of the cylinder, and then rotating it quickly?